# Strange result of a URL

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

```
http://!@#$%^&*().com
```

This seems to be an invalid URL and in fact browser says its an invalid URL.

But when I fetching this URL via file_get_contents (XAMPP), it gives an exception with "500 Internal Server Error", since this URL does not exist why am I not getting 404 ?

To check the response I'm using

```
$http_response_header
```

Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://!@#$%^&*().com";
$contents = @file_get_contents($url);   
print_r($http_response_header);
```

When I run the same on another machine (WAMP), then it says `$http_response_header` is an undefined variable.

Anybody has got any idea what's the problem here?

Comment: it is automatically populated with the response headers. it works well with other valid URL and return proper response.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are suppressing errors at the `file_get_contents` call, the domain you entered is actually invalid as you stated and the function call will return false and trigger the following warning

```
file_get_contents(http://.@#$%^&*().com): failed to open stream: operation failed
```

You won't get a 404 because the domain is invalid and the http request is probably never sent, hence your `$http_response_header` is empty.

Maybe a difference in OS or PHP version between XAMPP and WAMP explain why they act differently?

My advice is first checking the return value of file_get_contents and only when it's not false continue with inspecting the response headers.

Comment: You were right, but want to add a little more here. The machine where $http_response_header was being populated, was also running IIS with XAMPP, so for these sort of URLs the X-POWERED value is always IIS and ASP.NET

Comment: ok I got it .. $http_response_header was actually showing me the result of last call, if the URL is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting `404` because the domain does not exist. Try using valid domain. Using `http://.@#$%^&*().com` would return `failed to open stream: operation failed` while a valid domain would return `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed`

Please note one is `operation failed` and the other `HTTP request failed` you can only get HTTP error when there is HTTP request failed

Example

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");

$url = "http://stockoverflow.com/xxxx"; // URL does not exist 
$response = @file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($response,$http_response_header);
```

Output

```
boolean false
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' (length=22)  <--- you get your 404
  1 => string 'Content-Type: text/html' (length=23)
  2 => string 'Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5' (length=25)
  3 => string 'X-Powered-By: ASP.NET' (length=21)
  4 => string 'Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2012 10:26:20 GMT' (length=35)
  5 => string 'Connection: close' (length=17)
  6 => string 'Content-Length: 1245' (length=20)
```